# HttpWebRequest always fails after first fail

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

here is my problem : my winform periodically checks a thrid party webservice to get some data.

As long as there's no network problem, everything works fine ... But as soon as  I face one (VPN down, bad quality etc...), my app is unable to contact the webservice (got an

> "Unable to connect to remote server"

everytime, followed by a

> SocketException : "A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond").

I'm forced to restart my app to make it work again ...

I guess it's a problem of closing the connection or something but ... whatever I try (`WebRequest` or `HttpWebRequest`, closing response stream ...), the result is the same ... 
Here is my current code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strIdCredential, strPasswordCredential);
try
{
   string strReturnValue = "";
   using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
   {
      using (Stream data = response.GetResponseStream())
      {
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
         {
            strReturnValue = sr.ReadToEnd();
         }
         response.GetResponseStream().Close();
      }
   } 
   return strReturnValue;
}
catch (WebException e)
{
   using(var response = e.Response)
   {
      if (response != null)
        response.GetResponseStream().Close();
   }
   return cstrNetworkError;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ? Is it a security from the webservice ?

Comment: have you try to wrap `request` with `using(...)`? like this: `using (var request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl) as HttpWebRequest) { ... }`

Comment: Use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a to determine if connection is still openon both client ans server. I do not like the using statment because it does it own exception handling.  I rather have a try/catch to catch the exceptions.  In the exception handle you can add the Close() method which should fix the issue.  Right now when an exception occurs you  do not perform the Close().

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code, except maybe that the cleanup code is doing nothing. At the time you call `response.GetResponseStream().Close()`, the `StreamReader` is already disposed at the end of it's enclosing `using` block, which in turn will close the stream. The cleanup code in the catch block is useless as well and it could throw an exception that is not handled.

I know this doesn't solve your problem, but the issue is not obvious from the code you've supplied. I might suggest to try to avoid any possible caching of the error along the way by adding a query parameter with a different value at every call, in case the web service is kind enough to ignore it.